# Trouble going to different rooms in my basic Python text adventure

Tags: python

I am in a intro to programming class and have been trying to create a simple text adventure but every time that I (try) to go to a different room I get a name error saying that particular room isn't defined. I initially thought it was because I called the room after the else statement at the end and again right underneath it but that didn't change anything.

```
#This is a random text adventure game. Enjoy!

def main():
    print("You wake up in a cave without a clue of how you got there. Your head is throbbing. \nInsistent on figuring out what happened to you, you decide to explore the cave in search of answers. \n")
    print("You can do the following things: \n"
        "'go left' - Explore the tunnel on your left. \n"
        "'go right' - Explore the tunnel on your right. \n")
#Evaluates the player's choice.
    choice = input("What do you do?: ")
    if choice == 'go left':
        print("You stumble your way down the left tunnel.\n")
        left_cave()
    if choice == 'go right':
        print("You stumble your way down the right tunnel.\n")
        right_cave()
    else:
        print("That's not a direction.. Maybe your head is hurting because you don't know what left and right means. :D\n")
main()

#Defines the left cave.
def left_cave():
    print("After a short walk you find yourself in smaller room then the room you woke up in. \n There is some writing on the walls.")
    print("You can do the following things: \n"
        "'examine' - Examine the writing on the wall. \n"
        "'look around' - Take a look around the room. \n"
        "'go back' - Go back to the main room. \n")
    choice = input("What will you do?: ")
    if choice == 'examine':
        print("I see you have made it this far.  If you want to know what really happened to you then you will have to make it to the end of the cave.")
        middle_room()
    if choice == 'look around':
        print("You see just another darkly lit room.  This room smells.  You notice the writing on the wall again.")
        left_cave()
    if choice == 'go back':
        print("You make your way back to the room you woke up in.")
        main()
    else:
        print("There is nothing in this room that matches that.. C'mon.")
left_cave()
```

Comment: Don't know if it will solve your problem, but I think you should change most of your `if`s to `elif`s.

Comment: you dont have right_cave defined... what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I added another function but I was mainly referring to me trying to enter the left cave.  I didn't even try to enter the right.

Comment: call `main()` at the bottom ... after you define `left_cave`

Comment: I found out what was wrong, I was calling main at the end of the first bit and after moving it to the bottom it worked.  Well, I guess that's why I'm in an intro class.  -_- Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.  Thanks!